# distinguish exceptions of same type

Tags: java, exception

For example, the exception of type: java.net.BindException can throw a "Address already in use" (trying to bind a port that another program uses) or "Permission denied" (you do not have root permissions to open this port number).I do not own the class who throws BindException.

So, what is the best practice of distinguish these "different" Exceptions with the same type?

I am doing this, but I do not know if is a best practice:

```
try {
   //...some scary stuffs here  
 }
catch (BindException e){
            if (e.getMessage().contentEquals("Permission denied")){
                System.out.println("ERROR**You must be ROOT to bind that port address TCP:"+defaultPort);
            }
            else if (e.getMessage().contentEquals("Address already in use")){
                System.out.println("ERROR**Port TCP:"+defaultPort+" already in use by onother application");
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: If you are doing this in multiple parts of your code, then I suggest you take this out and place it in its own class, like a utility class.

Comment: Additionally, what I would do is to make a subclass for each kind of BindException.

Comment: no; this is just for example here; but tnx for collaboration.

Comment: Of course, you can just generalize that I've in my statement. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends. If this is code you own or have access to and a BindException is not appropriate then you should create your own exceptions:

```
public class PermissionDeniedException
```

You could even do:

```
public class PermissionDeniedBindException extends BindException
```

However, if this is not your class, then either the library you are using does not want you to distinguish between BindException's and is expecting you to behave in some generic manner when receiving the exception (ie just continuing or always trying again) OR this is an issue in the SDK. If the later is the case and this project is open source, I would recommend creating a pull request.

Otherwise, the third option is of course to do exactly as your are doing...but I would not recommend that at all as it is extremely fragile and could change just by modifying the message.

Comment: Also, some exceptions are thrown with null message, so assuming otherwise is dangerous. Rather than `e.getMessage().contentEquals("Permission denied")`, it's safer and more flexible to use a null check and startsWith() like so: `e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().startsWith("Permission denied")`

Comment: I don't own the class who throw these Exception. That class is java.net.ServerSocket. I Think the third option mentioned in your answer sounds good... if the library java.net dont change anything , off course.

Comment: Unless you want to modify the java.net API, I think you have no choice but to continue what you are doing. The best thing that you can do with that is to put everything in their own place in your code-base to make things organize and consistent.

Comment: The fact that the exceptions are hard to distinguish from each other signals that the writer of ServerSocket thought that you probably care less exactly which error you got. That you would provide the same error message to the user. Like a lot of programs do. They just output the message to the user which in my opinion is a good feedback.